# Athena query that returns result in json form

Tags: amazon-athena

I have several files that look like

```
{
   "column1":1,
   "column2":"A",
   "column3":{
      "column4":"B"
   }
}
```

I ran a crawler, which created the following table

[image]

I want to write a query that returns all of the columns in json form.
ie) I want it to return

```
Result

======================================

{"column1":1,"column2":"A","column3":{"column4":"B"}}

{"column1":1,"column2":"A","column3":{"column4":"B"}}
```

I've tried doing

```
SELECT CAST(
    SELECT * FROM data_source AS JSON) AS RESULT
```

Can someone point me in the right direction? Is this even possible?